# Angular 2 получить данные с html разметкой

Tags: angular2

Доброго времени,

пытаюсь сделать приложение с помощью Angular2.

Маршрутизация:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'first/:id', component: FirstComponent}
];
```

То есть, при переходе по адресу site/first/... управление переходит к компоненту FirstComponent и он может извлечь параметр id.
При запросе на site/first/item параметр id будет равен "item" и так далее.

В зависимости от этого параметра компонент с помощью сервиса посылает запрос на сервер для получения данных. На основе параметра id формируется адрес запроса. То есть в данном случае запрос будет на item.html.
Данные - это кусок html-кода, который будет вставлен на определенное место в шаблоне.

Вопрос: как мне получить эти данные именно в виде html. Пока получается только строку получить, и на страницу она вставляется прям вместе с тегами.

Сервис, запрашивающий нужный файл:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{

    constructor(private http: Http){ }

    getData(address: string){
        return this.http.get(address);
    }
}
```

Вот так я получаю данные в компоненте:

```
this.httpService.getData('data.html').subscribe((data: Response) => this.code=data.text());
```

Я так понимаю, что дело в используемом методе text(), из-за него возвращается строка.
Как мне правильно получить данные в виде html, если в запрашиваемом файле они именно в виде простой html-разметки?

Нужно ли воспользоваться каким-то другим методом класса Response (о котором я не знаю) или как-то обработать полученную строку (каким образом?) или использовать json (то есть исходные данные нужно будет как-то привести к этому формату?)

Подскажите, пожалуйста :)
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: как это вставляется на страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При вставке переменной через интерполяцию {{}} или присвоении innerHTMLпо умолчанию HTML будет экранирован, по причинам безопасности.

Подробно тут: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

> Interpolated content is always escaped—the HTML is not interpreted, and the browser displays angle brackets in the element's text content.
>
> For the HTML to be interpreted, you must bind it to an HTML property
>   such as innerHTML. But binding a value that an attacker might control
>   into innerHTML normally causes an XSS vulnerability.

Соответственно чтобы обойти это надо пометить, что вы доверяете этому коду, но это потенциальная дыра.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
...

this.httpService.getData('data.html').subscribe((data: Response) => this.code=sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data.text()));
```

Comment: На странице, на которую вы меня отправили, нашла вот эту прелесть: 

`<p class="e2e-inner-html-bound" [innerHTML]="htmlSnippet"></p>`

html-форматирование сохраняется, а скрипты игнорируются) Спасибо огромное! Всю голову сломала))